# In Spelunky HD what secret characters are there are how do you unlock them?

Tags: spelunky-hd

What secret characters can you unlock in Spelunky HD and how do you find them?

Please be specific as to what version characters are in, as they could well be different on different platforms.

Comment: I'm asking about the Xbox 360 version of Spelunky, not any PC version (where I'm sure the characters available are different). Please don't edit the question to change what it's about.

Comment: The 2012 Xbox-360 version of the game is known as [Spelunky HD](http://spelunky.wikia.com/wiki/Spelunky) according to the wiki, so I'd retag with that at least. On the platform front, it'd be better to have answer(s) that cover all platforms. It's not hard to say *"Here are the secret characters (1,2,3). **Xbox 360** exclusive characters are (4,5,6) and the **PC** exclusive characters are (7,8,9)"*. I'm not going to edit-war with you over this, but I'm saying this question can (and should) cover all platforms, to be as useful to future visitors as possible.

Comment: @Robotnik ok. I rolled back the other edits because I started getting answers on how to hack the save files on PC, which was specifically what I didn't want. I've updated it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the full list of unlockable characters for Spelunky.

The characters marked "PC version only" can only be unlocked in the game in the PC version of Spelunky. To unlock them in the XBLA version you need to purchase the [Explorers DLC](http://marketplace.xbox.com/en-US/Product/Spelunky-Explorers-DLC/679e4fab-f0f1-4b27-9601-aa453443a80e), which will unlock all "PC version only" characters instantly. These characters are also not counted towards the "Entire Gang" achievement.

## Already Unlocked

These four characters are available from the beginning:

### Spelunker

[image: Spekunker]

### Blue

[image: Blue Guy]

### Red

[image: Red Turban Guy]

### Green

[image: Green Girl]

## Random Coffins

These four characters appear in coffins placed randomly in each of the four areas (Mines, Jungle, Ice Caves, Temple). You will only ever find one of *these* random coffins in each area.

To release the character, just whip or *attack* the coffin.

### Yellow Miner Girl

[image: Yellow Miner Girl]

### Mariachi Man

[image: Lime Mariachi Man]

### Purple Pirate Girl

[image: Purple Pirate Girl]

### Bear Suit Guy

[image: Cyan Bear Suit Guy]

## Hidden Coffins

These characters are trapped in coffins that can only be found in a specific area.

Just whip or attack the coffin to release the character.

### Round Boy (PC version only)

[image: Round Boy]

This coffin can be found in a Tikki Man Village in the Jungle.

### Round Girl (PC version only)

[image: Round Girl]

This coffin can be found in the "My skin is crawling" event in the Mines.

### Eskimo (PC version only)

[image: Eskimo]

This coffin can be found in the "It smells like wet fur in here" event in the Ice Caves.

### Viking (PC version only)

[image: Viking]

The Viking's coffin can be found in the "I hear rushing water" event in the Jungle.

### Ninja (PC version only)

[image: Ninja]

The coffin containing the Ninja can be found in the area to the top of Olmec's Lair.

### Golden Monk (PC version only)

[image: Golden Monk]

The Golden Monk is trapped in a coffin in the City of Gold.

### Van Helsing

[image: Van Helsing Vampire Hunter]

This coffin is at the top of the castle in the Haunted Castle secret level.

### Robot (PC version only)

[image: Robot]

The robot can be found in the secret Mothership area. You can find this area by entering the big building to the side of the level on level 3-4 "It feels like the fourth of July". The robot is in a pod (not a coffin), usually close to the Alien Queen.

### Meat Boy

[image: Super Meat Boy]

Meat Boy can be found in the Worm secret level, near the bottom in a goo sac (not a coffin).

## Other Characters

### Jungle Warrior

[image: Jungle Tribal Warrior]

This character is automatically unlocked when you defeat Olmec and finish the game by exiting the level. Shortcuts are allowed.

### Yang

[image: Yang]

Yang is automatically unlocked when you defeat King Yama (in Hell) and finish the game by exiting the level.

### Cyclops (PC version only)

[image: Cyclops]

The Cyclops can be found in a Hired Hand stall in the Black Market. You can either buy him, or anger the shopkeepers (try whipping him).

Comment: Ok, that's an answer for the PC version (+1), if you could confirm which of those are available on the XBox version you can have the answer too :-)

Comment: All of the characters marked "PC version" are available on the XBLA version as well, but they're only available through paid DLC. I don't know offhand about the PS3 version.

Comment: @cloudymusic I've already mentioned this at the beginning of my post

Answer (score 6):

There are 4 secondary coloured (yellow, lime, cyan and purple) characters that randomly appear in a coffin:

[image: yellow]
[image: lime]
[image: cyan]
[image: purple]

The jaguar warrior character is unlocked by beating the game:

[image: jaguar warrior]

Super meat boy is found in a green sack near the bottom of the secret worm level:

[image: super meat boy]

In a coffin in the secret haunted castle level is the vampire hunter:

[image: vampire hunter]

Finally, Yang can be unlocked after beating the secret hell level:

[image: yang]

Comment: very cool man!!!!

Comment: To confirm, you unlock Yang if you complete Hell.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you are familiar with hex editing, you can change bytes `0A20`, `0A24`, ..., `0A60` to `01` in `spelunky_save.sav`, giving you all the characters Keith mentioned, plus a robot, an ogre, a girl in green, etc.

Comment: Sorry, someone edited my question, I'm asking specifically about the Xbox 360 version of Spelunky - not how to hack the PC version (original or HD)